# Adjust a Bokeh DataTable to the window

Tags: datatable, screen, bokeh

I would like to automatically adjust the width of a bokeh DataTable to the size of a screen. But I do not find the right way to do it. This line of code is supposed to work :

`data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, height = 300, sizing_mode = 'scale_width', fit_columns=True)`

But it does not. My Datatable keeps the same width.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible with the current implementation of `DataTable` - if you don't specify an explicit width in pixels, the width will be set to `600px`.

You're welcome to create a feature request on Bokeh's GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.2.3 and likely earlier you can use [`sizing_mode`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DataTable.sizing_mode):

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, random, string
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.plotting import show

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 12)), columns=[(random.randint(1,30) * random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)) for col in range(12)])

data_table = DataTable(columns = [TableColumn(field=c, title=c) for c in df.columns], sizing_mode='stretch_width', source = ColumnDataSource(df))

show(data_table)
```